# Webpack merge header template to header tag

Tags: html, node.js, webpack, build, html-webpack-plugin

I am using **WEBPACK** and **HtmlWebpackPlugin** also.
I have created static header.html which is static file, and I want content of this file to be appended to all files in project in `<header>` tag.

And I want to do same for footer.html
So that when I am building project using Webpack I have html files with header and footer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HtmlWebpackPlugin` like this.

```
plugins : [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/index.html'
        filename: './index.html'
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/header.html',
        filename: './header.html'
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/footer.html',
        filename: './footer.html'
    }),
    ...
]
```

this will help you. :)